# I'm getting "CGI Error: File is not a perl storable" error

Tags: perl, cgi, storable

I'm having an issue were my perl suddently and without any reason started throwing this exception back to me:

CGI Error: File is not a perl storable at blib\lib\Storable.pm (autosplit into blib\lib\auto\Storable_retrieve.al) line 380, at C:/myapp/src/main/perl/lib/Output.pm line 1831

Does anybody have any idea what the "File is not a perl storable at blib\lib\Storable.pm" is about and how to fix this?

Thanks,
goe

Comment: When posting a question like this, you *really* should post the code that is causing the error.  Even though ikegami might be able to guess the answer even without code :)

Comment: As I wrote below, there are no code changes in my SVN. This issue started happening on its own just like that. I was however upgraded to an SSD so maybe the image got corrupted and is affecting my perl installation.

Comment: But this error doesn't imply code changes at all. It implies that the file that you are reading has changed.

Comment: Right, that why I suspect the image of my old HDD was corrupted when transferred to the SSD and it's affecting that file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did something like

```
use Storable qw( retrieve );
my $data = retrieve('file.dat');
```

and `file.dat` isn't in a format Storable recognises.

Comment: Well, you would think so but my SVN says no files have been modified. So I made no changes in my perl code yet suddenly I started getting this exception and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: What's the output of `perl -MStorable -le"binmode STDIN; read(STDIN, $h, 12); print for $], $Storable::VERSION, unpack 'H*', $h" < file.dat` (Replace `file.dat` with the name of file that gives the error.) It gives some version and the first 12 bytes of the file.

Comment: Never mind, I resolved the issue. Some of perl files where empty to the my upgrade and there causing this issue with perl.